# How to filter array of items with multiple dropdowns on single angularjs custom filter function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am facing a problem with the filter function in Angularjs, here I used a common function ng-change for multiple a dropdown. But when I select  All(default options) I am getting an empty array of filtered items.

Here is my code

Javascript:

```
function customFilters() {
    vm.filteredItems = $filter('filter')(vm.claimsResData, {
        status: vm.status,
        member: vm.member,
        treatment: vm.treatment
    });
}
```

Html:

```
<select ng-model="vm.member" class="form-control"
        ng-options="names for names in vm.memberNames"
        ng-change="vm.customFilters()">
    <option value="">All Members</option>
</select>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Update your function as below, because when you want to exclude a key from filter you've to pass `undefined` to its value, but in your code you are passing blank string i.e., `""`

```
function customFilters() {
    vm.filteredItems = $filter('filter')(vm.claimsResData, {
        status: vm.status,
        member: vm.member || undefined,
        treatment: vm.treatment
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only add the selection to the pattern object if the selection is truthy:

```
function customFilters() {
    var patternObj = {}

    vm.status && patternObj.status = vm.status;
    vm.member && patternObj.member = vm.member;
    vm.treatment && patternObj.treatment = vm.treatment;

    vm.filteredItems = $filter('filter')(vm.claimsResData, patternObj);
}
```

A pattern object is used to filter specific properties on objects contained by the array. When that property exists on the pattern object, the objects in the array must have that property.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS filter Filter API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)